# ScrollController.jumpTo() "ScrollController not attached to any scroll views"

Tags: flutter

I am listening to a PageController to get the position and then syncing it with a ListView. When the PageView is manipulated the ListView is simultaneously manipulated.

Example: https://github.com/Ramotion/cardslider-android

However, after v0.6.0 I get an assertion error that my ScrollController is not attached to any views. This fires every time there is a stream event triggering the `.jumpTo()` method. It still works but the assertion error is driving me nuts.

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 169 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:40:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      ScrollController.jumpTo (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:169:12)
#3      MyTitle.build.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/lukepighetti/code/when-coin/when_coin_2/lib/screens/rate/widgets/title.dart:19:19)
#4      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#6      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:584:14)
#7      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:700:11)
#8      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:660:7)
#9      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#10     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

How do I use `ScrollController.jumpTo()` without running into this exception?

```
class MyTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Category> categories;
  MyTitle({this.categories});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _controller = ScrollController();
    double height = 36.0;
    // double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8;

    BlocProvider.of(context).page.listen((page) {
      _controller.jumpTo(height * page);
    });

    return Container(
      height: height,
      // width: width,
      child: ListView(
        controller: _controller,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: categories
            .map((c) => _Title(
                  title: c.title,
                  index: categories.indexOf(c),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My mistake was that I attached the controller to `Scrollbar` instead of `SingleChildScrollView` `child: Scrollbar( child: SingleChildScrollView( controller: _scrollController,` . I thought I should share in case any of you might have a similar situation.

Answer (score 18):

As the answer above me states, you are using the ScrollController when it is not yet attached to the ListView or other ScrollView. You can check this with the hasClients attribute.

```js
if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
  await _scrollController.animateTo(
    0.0,
    curve: Curves.easeOut,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  );
}
```

Comment: 'await' might not be defined, but I was able to solve such issue with the solution above without the await function.

Comment: @bks I meant that I could use the solution Sam Smets gave too just without the 'await' word

Comment: @Raycherr Ok I understand- for me it eventually didn't work.

Comment: @SamSmets this `hasClients` check resolved the above occurring issue.

Answer (score 5):

check controller has client ant then delay jump:

```
if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
        _scrollController?.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Avoid using `Future.delayed()`. Instead, use `WidgetBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are re-creating `_controller` and subscribes to it on each `build`. The controller must be created once as final class-scoped property. Moreover you should use `StatefulWidget` to `dispose` controller and subsribe to stream in `initState` method.

```
class MyTitle extends StatefullWidget {
 MyTitle({this.categories});

 final List<Category> categories;

_MyTitleState createState() => _MyTitleState();
}

class _MyTitleState extends State<MyTitle> {
  final _controller = ScrollController(); // <--
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BlocProvider.of(context, listen: false).page.listen((page) {
      if(_constoller.hasClients) {
      _controller.jumpTo(height * page);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = 36.0;
    // double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8;

    return Container(
      height: height,
      // width: width,
      child: ListView(
        controller: _controller,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: categories
            .map((c) => _Title(
                  title: c.title,
                  index: categories.indexOf(c),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone that wants another approach could use [Flutter After Layout](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_after_layout)

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
  }
```

`yourFunction` will be executed after the layout is completed.

Comment: this is much better.

Answer (score -1):

check controller does not have client ant then delay jump:

```
if (!_scrollController.hasClients) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
        _scrollController?.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to jump using `scrollController` before adding the `scrollController` to the `ScrollView`(List view). We have to jump after adding to controller. Refer below code.

```
 // task1
 Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => 
 { // task2
  BlocProvider.of(context).page.listen((page) { _controller.jumpTo(height * page); }); 
 });
// task3
```

This is very similar to `DispatchQueue.main.async` as the duration is *zero*. Order of execution will be task1, task3, task2

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. The stream, and thus the jumpTo event, is firing and throwing the assertion long after the page has been built. It seems to throw the assertion for every frame. The solution also doesn't work.